# prevent php timeout exception for image uploads

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, timeoutexception

I have an ajax image uploader that sends images to a php script, so that they are validated / resized & saved into a directory. The ajax uploader allows multiple files to be uploaded at the same time. Since it allows multiple files there can be timeouts, so I thought of increasing the execution time using set_time_limit. But I am having trouble determining how much time I have to set, since the default is 30sec. Will 1min be enough? The images are uploading properly in my local machine, but I am having thoughts that there will be timeout errors on a shared hosting service. Any ideas & thoughts on how others have implemented will be valuable.. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than iterate through and process all of the image uploads on the server side, why not iterate through each file on the Client Side and run the PHP script once for each image?

Comment: @maiorano84's suggestion is a very good one. Also, the amount of time required will depend tremendously on the size of the images.  If we're talking profile pictures, say 200 kB, then 30 seconds is plenty.  If we're talking huge, high-res, panoramic shots, or medical images, or other huge files, a minute may be way too short.

Comment: @maiorano84 I am sending individual requests for each upload. So that must mean that I am processing once for each image. The problem is that I allow simultaneous uploads & this might increase the time required.

Comment: @EdCottrell The maximum file size that I allow is 5MB, so is there any way for me to calculate the time required, because I don't want users to have timeout issues. thanks..

Comment: 5 MB is not huge.  Just set it for a minute and monitor how many users time out.  If it turns out to be a lot, do something like what @flcoder suggested.  My suspicion is that this is a case of premature optimization, and most users will complete their uploads in far less than a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it to 5 minutes if you need to.  But for obvious reasons, you don't really want to have it that high especially for http calls.

So... if I had the energy, this is what I'd do...

I need:

process_initializer.php

process_checker.php

client.html

the_process.php (runs as background)

...

client uploads files to process_initializer.

initializer creates a unique ID, maybe based off of time with milliseconds or some other advanced solution

initializer starts a background process, sending it necessary arguments like filenames along with the ID

initializer responds to the client with ID

client then polls process_checker to see what's going on with ID (maybe 20 second intervals - setTimeout(), whatever)

process_checker may check to see if file output_ID.txt exists which the_process should create when it's done and then if it doesn't exist respond to the client that it's not ready, if it does, maybe send the output to the client and then the client can do whatever.

---

When apache runs php, it uses one php.ini configuration and when you run php from the command line or from another script like `exec('php the_process arg1 arg2')` it will use a different php.ini for this, reffered to as php cli or something like that unless you have php cli configured to use the same php.ini that apache does.  Important thing is, it's possible they use different settings and so you can let cli scripts take more time than your http called scripts.